# For all feminine nouns, do I use tout, tous, or toutes as an adverb?

Tags: tout-tous

Comment remplacer les noms féminins ici dans "Aucun magasin n'a en stock des [échalotes, mâches](https://agreenmouse.com/french-names-for-fruit/)"?

- Aucun magasin les a en stock [toutes](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-have-all-of-them.1566468/post-7887160) ?
- Aucun magasin les a en stock [tous](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-have-spoken-to-all-of-them.2382666/post-11974841) ?

ou

- Aucun magasin les a en stock tout ?

Answer (score 4):

I would first slightly rephrase the initial question:

> Aucun magasin n'a en stock des aubergines et de la mâche.

You can't skip the partitive article in such a list and *mâche* is more often used as uncountable.

The second proposal is the closer one but locating the pronoun before *en stock* is more idiomatic. In addition, the negative particle *ne* is expected in written or formal French:

> *Aucun magasin **ne** les a tous en stock.* (*tous* referring to *ces légumes*).

I wouldn't say *aucun magasin ne les a toutes en stock*, probably because *légumes* is masculine and you use a partitive article. The feminine would work with:

> Les échalottes et la mâche dont on a besoin, il ne les a pas toutes en stock.

You might also say, to avoid the issue :

> *Aucun magasin n'a tout en stock.*

Note: In the third link present in your question (wordreference: *[I have spoken to all of them](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-have-spoken-to-all-of-them.2382666/#post-11974841)*), a sentence is reported to be incorrect although it is in fact much more usual and idiomatic than the only one marked as correct:

> Je leur ai tous parlé. ✔? (rare)
> Je leur ai parlé tous. ✘
> Je leur ai parlé à tous. ✔ (usual)

Comment: Merci! I just want to clarify...you aren't treating "les" as referring to my feminine nouns? You wrote "tous referring to ces légumes". Can you interpret "tous" as referring to my feminine nouns? Don't refer to "ces légumes" because it's masculin, and I still am uncertain what role "toutes" plays here.

Comment: « J'ai parlé à chacun d'eux » est une proposition de *deepL* beaucoup plus littéraire et audible.

Comment: 1. correct, *les* doesn't refer to the feminine nouns. 2. *Tous* can't directly refer to feminine nouns. 3. The issue is with the partitive: *l'eau* is feminine but *de l'eau* is "neutral".

Comment: @Personne Possible, mais ça n'aide pas à apprendre à utiliser *tous* et *toutes*. *J'ai parlé à chacun d'eux* est plus rare que *j'ai parlé à chacun d'entre eux*. On peut aussi trouver une petite nuance entre le collectif *tous* et l'individuel *chacun* : *I have spoken to all of them* vs *I have spoken to each (one) of them*.

Comment: C'est plus un problème de difficultés de traduction que de grammaire … problème qui t'as obligé à reformuler la question pour prendre en compte deux points de vue différents dans la façon d'exprimer la pensée.